# Firestore security rules for nested collections

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

my security rules are as follows:

```
match /xxx/{yyy}{
    allow read: if resource.data.zzzId == request.auth.uid;
}    
match /xxx/{yyy}/aaa/{bbb}{
    allow read: if resource.data.zzzId == request.auth.uid;
}
```

The field `zzzId` is present in both the `yyy` and `bbb` documents and has the same value. Now, in an Android app I have two `FirestoreRecyclerAdapters`, one for documents in `xxx` collection and an inner one, for documents in `aaa` collection. The first adapter displays data, while the other fails with `InsufficientPermisions` error.

I've done some blind testing with security rules and I've validated that the request for `bbb` document has `request.auth.uid` set and when I hardcode the value to compare it to, it works. Therefore there must be something wrong going on with the `resource.data.zzzId` part, ie. it gets the wrong value (or maybe no value at all) inside the rule.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a wrong way of querying the data in subcollections. When I added a `whereEqualTo` clause for the `zzzId` field, it all works. Firebase documentation actually mentions it somewhere, but I can't find it now.